# mvn jetty:run giving error 404

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jetty

I have a Spring MVC web application and tried running it using Jetty. But whenever I type

> mvn jetty: run

I get the proper sequence of events ending in "Jetty Server Started"

But however when I try to open the browser and type in

```
http:localhost:8080/app
```

I get Error 404 page Not found

here is my pom.xml jetty part

```
<plugin>
  <!-- This plugin is needed for the servlet example -->
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.2.0.v20101020</version>
  <configuration>
    <webApp>
      <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
    </webApp>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my controller is mapped to @RequestMapping("/") and my servlet is also mapped to /. The pom.xml build name is app thus the URL is `http://localhost:8080/app`

Any help with this would be great.
I have also tried with Jetty v9 and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this it works fine

**Edit**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.8</version>
       <configuration>
          <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

First thing `http:localhost:8080/app` is wrong it should be `http://localhost:8080/app` if you give this url then you must have a landing page that you can specify in web.xml
Like this

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So simply try to access the url `http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp` where there must be some index.jsp under the web-content folder

Comment: Sorry I had missed saying that I tried that as well and it was still giving me the same error 404. I have now edited the question to reflect that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @SparkOn  I tried that, but I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: are you trying with this url `http:localhost:8080/app`

Comment: yes, I am getting the same "Request URI Notfound error" when I use that UEL. :(

Comment: First thing `http:localhost:8080/app` is wrong it should be `http://localhost:8080/app` if you give this url then you must have a landing page that you can specify in web.xml's <welcome-file>

Comment: haha true I meant http:// (with two slashes) but after seeing ur comment, I tried both anyways, still same error.

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp`  where there must be some index.jsp under the web-content folder

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you :) @SparkOn! You can edit your answer as well in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Note: Jetty 6.x is no longer considered secure, it was EOL'd in early 2010 and has no security updates since then.  Use Jetty 9 to stay current.

Comment: note that you can use org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin if you are looking for an updated jetty maven plugin.